# Android - Change payment method popup is empty

Tags: android, payment, in-app, is-empty

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/876916/img/Android_payment_method_empty.png - Screenshot

Two weeks ago some users with different Android 4+ versions started to report an issue (3-4 users each week). All of them was going to do first purchase on Market, but they didn't enter payment method before.

So when such user pressing in-app purchase, market asking them to enter payment method info, but there is no "Enter Credit or Debit card number" button in appearing popup.

I can not reproduce this issue (tried 6 different devices with 6 different 4+ android versions, even 4.4.4 and 5.0). After this we asked one user to try different application, and he said that this bug is appearing in other apps too!

There are no any information about this on the internet. So does anyone know other method to show "Enter Credit or Debit card number" button? Or maybe someone had same problem and solved it?

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4646404?hl=en 

the users didn't set there payment methods